# How to import subroutines from modules in perl

Tags: perl, module, export, subroutine

I am novice in perl. I have this sample code.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# Calcu.pm

package Calc;

sub add {
    ( $one , $two ) = @_;
    $total = $one + $two;
    return $total;
    }

1;
```

&

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# add.pl

use Calcu;

print Calcu::add(50, 60);
```

script add.pl is running fine. but I want to call the `add` method without mentioning its module name. I googled & added below lines in my Calcu.pm

```
use Exporter;

@ISA = (Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw (add);
```

& replace `print Calcu::add(50, 60);` with `print add(50, 60);` in add.pl but it is still giving me the below error.

```
Undefined subroutine &main::add called at add.pl
```

Is there any way possible so that I can directly call add subroutine in my ad.pl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `package Calc;` to `package Calcu;` in Calcu.pm

The mismatch in package names is what is giving you trouble.

Have a read through [perldoc Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) for the gory details.

Have a look at [perldoc perlootut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) for an overview of different ways in perl to create objects.